# Xamarin UITableViewCell Memory Leak

Tags: uitableview, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin and classes that inherit UITableViewController, UITableViewSource, and UITableViewCell to provide a simple list of items.
I find that once garbage collection has run, the UITableViewController and UITableViewSource get collected, but the UITableViewCell's never get disposed and collected properly.

Here's my example code.

```
public class Test1ButtonCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("Test1ButtonCell");

    public Test1ButtonCell () : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, Key)
    {
        TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        TextLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
    }

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose (disposing);
    }
}

public class Test1Controller : UITableViewController
{
    private WeakReference<Test1Source> source = null;


    public Test1Controller () : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        List<String> testdata = new List<String>( );
        for( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
        {
            testdata.Add( i.ToString( ) );
        }


        source = new WeakReference<Test1Source>(new Test1Source( this,testdata ));

        testdata = null;

        this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem  ("Back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        this.NavigationItem.Title="Test1";

        TableView.Source = source.target;

        this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.Clicked += HandleBackButtonTouch;

    }
    public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.Clicked -= HandleBackButtonTouch;

        base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);

        TableView.Source = null;
    }


    private void HandleBackButtonTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationController.PopToRootViewController( true );
    }

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing) 
    { 

        base.Dispose (disposing); 
    } 

}

public class Test1Source : UITableViewSource
{
    private WeakReference<Test1Controller> controller;

    private List<String> testdata = new List<string>();


    public Test1Source (Test1Controller controller, List<String> testData)
    {
        testdata = testData;
        this.controller = new WeakReference<Test1Controller>( controller );
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        if( section == 0 )
        {
            return testdata.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (Test1ButtonCell.Key) as Test1ButtonCell;
        if( cell == null )
        {
            cell = new Test1ButtonCell( );
        }

        if( indexPath.Section == 0 )
        {
            cell.TextLabel.Text = testdata[ indexPath.Row ];
        }

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView caches (and reuses) UITableViewCells.

They'll go away once the UITableView is freed.

Comment: I guess my question then is how and when does UITableView get freed.  After I leave this controller by calling NavigationController.PopToRootViewController.  I call GC.Collect manually.  In instruments I see my UITableViewSource and UITableViewController classes disappear at this point, but a whole bunch of other stuff including the UITableView and the cells never seem to get collected.  I would expect that when the Controller class has been garbage collected that the UITableView would be gone as well.

Comment: You might be running into a circular reference crossing the native-managed border. You can find more information about this here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4931/summary-of-current-best-practices-for-event-handlers-and-disposing

Comment: Even if you call UITableView.Dispose, it won't dispose custom cells. At least that's the bug, I believe.

Comment: Also of note, it works properly on simulator, but not on the device, so definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the problem. It works properly on the simulator and not on the device.

The only thing I can think of is to keep somewhere list of all created custom cells (by adding them to the list in the constructor of the cell) and dispose them when the table is disposed. Kind of ugly, but it works.